# What to do with original API when using a API-Gateway

Tags: microservices, keycloak, api-design, api-gateway, kong

I'm wondering what to do with an API Endpoint when using a API Gateway. For example when you following the tutorial here: https://wiredcraft.com/blog/securing-components-in-a-microservice-context

You are using keycloak and kong (api-gateway) to secure the api. With kong you're getting an new Endpoint under http://localhost:8000/data. But the "original" express Server is still listening on http://localhost:3001/data.

That means that when a user/attacker knows the url of the "orignal" service and doesn't use the kong url (port 8000) he/she can still work with the api.

So my question is about the strategy and what to do with the original api? How could that be secured. Shall we implement the keycloak request on the api as well? But where are the benefits of kong then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API gateway gives you a single entrypoint that [simplifies how client applications access your services](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html). You could add keycloak security on the gateway and not on the services behind - perhaps if you've a setup where you can block network access for clients to any services except the gateway. But even then you might still want the gateway and keycloak on the services behind.

The reason you might put keycloak on the services behind is because they are likely to need to know the identity of the user making the request. If they are going to read the token anyway then it might be most straightforward to add keycloak to them. And you'd still want the gateway to simplify life for clients. You'd then also want the gateway to forward the token to the services behind the gateway. (We're using keycloak and spring cloud gateway on the Activiti Cloud project and this is essentially how we decided to secure the services themselves with keycloak and have the gateway forward the token to them.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped a lot! At the moment I have keycloak sitting on my api-gateway. So I will nee to figure out how this beahves in a docker enironment. My microservice has a portmapping, which I need to connect that service to my microservice gateway. So maybe one solution would be to block all other traffic except the traffic coming from my api-gateway.